# Difference between field definition and initialization?

Tags: java, field

What is the difference between field definition and initialization?

I think a field definition is the whole statement
    e.g. **int a = 1;**

and intialization the assignment part
    int a **= 1**;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initializing Fields

```
public class Example {

// initialize to false
private boolean full = false;

// initialize to 2
public static int a= 2;
```

}

Field Definiton:

```
public class Employee {
    String name;
    String position;
    int salary;
    Date hiredDate;
}
```